# Unable to Bridge Substrate-Template-Node to Rialto

Tags: parity-bridges-common

I have been experimenting with the [substrate-relay](https://github.com/freeverseio/parity-bridges-common) application and successfully bridged `Millau` to `Rialto` following the standard example. Now, I am trying to bridge the [substrate-template-node](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) to `Rialto`.

My approach has been to **substitute the Millau node with a substrate-template-node**. Unfortunately, this has resulted in an issue.

When I try to establish this bridge, the relay fails to connect to the substrate-template-node and provides the following error message:

```
ERROR bridge Failed to connect to Millau node: RpcError(ParseError(Error("invalid length 64, expected a (both 0x-prefixed or not) hex string or byte array containing 64 bytes", line: 0, column: 0))).
```

I am wondering if it is necessary to implement additional code to enable the relay to connect to the chain I am aiming for? Any advice or insight on how to troubleshoot this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Millau uses a non-standard [64-bytes hash](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/master/primitives/chain-millau/src/millau_hash.rs) to demonstrate that the bridge (runtime and offchain relayer) can support chains that are using non-standard primitives. So if you're providing your (`substrate-template-node` based chain) chain endpoint where relayer expects to find Millau, you'll get this error.

We don't (yet) have a generic relayer that may connect to the chain, read its metadata and start relaying headers/messages. That's something we've planned for the future (and obviously this "generic" mechanism will never work with Millau-like chains, because metadata would never contain a **code** to compute some hash). Right now to add a relayer support for a new chain, you should:

- define its basic (runtime-level) primitives (hash, block number, header, ...). Example: [bp-rialto](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/tree/master/primitives/chain-rialto);
- define its relayer-level primitives, used to sign transactions. Example: [relay-rialto-client](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/tree/master/relays/client-rialto);
- manually add support for your new chain to the relayer itself. Relayer has many subcommands, so you should decide what's to support. Example: [init-bridge subcommand](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/1593860e7b637a277455f0c37f5ab834d25981d1/relays/bin-substrate/src/cli/init_bridge.rs#L66).

A more detailed example, which adds support for bridge between Kusama Bridge Hub and Polkadot Bridge Hub: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/pull/1982